# Getting string as result from MySQL in PHP - string always empty?

Tags: php, mysql

First, I've done my homework (researched), but this is more like a bug inside my code that drives me crazy and I need help from more eyes to solve it. So please if someone have an idea why is this happening?

The problem:

1. In a MySQL table I am keeping a project id's as a "1,2,3,4,"
2. Then via ajax I'm checking if some project_id is part from this
   string or not, so if its not part I try to add it (example, if 13 is
   part from the above) and after update should be "1,2,3,4,13," but
   somehow always I'm ending with "13,".

Here's the relevant part of the code that Im trying to fix:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `assigned_projects` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`=`$user_id`");
$user_proekti = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$str_proekti = $user_proekti[0];

if (!(strpos($str_proekti, $proekt))) {            
    //Means that the project is not in the list and should be added
    $new_proekti = $str_proekti.$proekt.","; //$str_proekti is always empty string??????
    $assign_new_project = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `assigned_projects` = `$new_proekti` WHERE `user_name` = `$dodeleno` ");
    $update_track_changes = mysql_query("UPDATE `track_changes` SET `proekts_order` = `1`");
}
```

Comment: Instead of trying to use `strpos` use `explode` and `in_array` and simply use `array_pop` or `array_push` along with, to `remove` or `add` respectively within array and finally use `implode` to bind again using `,`

Comment: I tried yesterday with explode which gives me last empty element and than array_pop to remove it and finally array push to add the new one. But when it comes to update it in the database - still empty, not even the last id... maybe I had a wrong use of the implode to get all the elements back in string. I'll give it one more try and let you know how it went. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try it like as

```
$str = "1,2,3,4,";
$input = "13";
$arr = array_filter(explode(',', $str));
if (!in_array($input, $arr)) {
    array_push($arr, $input);
}
echo implode(',', $arr);
```